# google Speech API for iOS Out of vocabulary training set

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am working on a project which uses Google Speech API in iOS project. The project involves Voice input to recognize many terms which are basically jargons. The Google speech API gracefully fails to recognize this voice input for this jargons.

Is there a way to train google speech API to learn this jargons and easily recognize them while giving voice input in mobile iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to (recently rebranded) Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API. If so, there is no way to train it right now.

Comment: Yes. But I saw few links on the google developers, which had a faint idea to do so. I could not understand how to do it. Pasting the link here: [link](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#phrase-hints) if you can help me out.